# python - Error while importing PubNub

Tags: python, python-3.x, pubnub

When I am trying to import the `pubnub` library, I am getting the following error. I am not able to understand the cause of the problem. Please help.

```
>>> import pubnub
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pubnub
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pubnub.py", line 152, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\reactor.py", line 38, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 56, in <module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 50, in _getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\udp.py", line 53, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import base, defer, address
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 23, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import fdesc, main, error, abstract, defer, threads
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 29, in <module>
    from twisted.python import lockfile, failure
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\lockfile.py", line 52, in <module>
    _open = file
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

What can I do to remove this error? This error appears even when I use commands like `from pubnub import Pubnub`.

**EDIT:** The error above has been solved but now a new error has occured. `from pubnub import Pubnub` was working fine in the Python shell but when I run it from my file I get an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Pubnub'`.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a version of Twisted that works with Python 3.x.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `from pubnub import Pubnub` was working fine in the Python shell but when I run it from my file I get an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Pubnub'`.

Comment: You have multiple Python installations. Not all have Pubnub installed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have a Python 3.4 one only.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So should I repair my Python 3.4?

Comment: No, you should find out which installation the script is using.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How do I do that? I want to change the installation which my script is using to 3.4.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't know what's wrong. `from pubnub import Pubnub` works fine in IDLE but not in PyCharm. What should I do?